# Decrypting using AWS go sdk

Tags: aws-sdk-go

I'm new to Golang, and am stuck on this issue for a day already.
I am trying to write a small code snippet that decrypts (using AWS go sdk) the cipher text which was previously encrypted (using AWS python sdk). I don't see any problem doing this since the encrypted value is just a base64 encoded string, but I keep running into this error, `InvalidCiphertextException`, when trying to decrypt.

Here's my GO code:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/kms"

    "fmt"
    "os"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    b64 "encoding/base64"
)

func main() {
    // Initialize a session in us-west-2 that the SDK will use to load
    // credentials from the shared credentials file ~/.aws/credentials.
    sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String("us-east-1")},
    )
    fmt.Println(err)
    // Create KMS service client
    svc := kms.New(sess)
    ciphertext_regular := "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"
    data, err1 := b64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(ciphertext_regular)

    // Decrypt the data
    result1, err1 := svc.Decrypt(&kms.DecryptInput{CiphertextBlob: data})

    if err1 != nil {
        fmt.Println("Got error decrypting data: ", err1)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    blob_string := string(result1.Plaintext)

    fmt.Println(blob_string)
}
```

I've tried to look it up online, and it seems like people are doing the same thing as me. ([here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/issues/1082))

The complete error message:

```
Got error decrypting data:  InvalidCiphertextException: 
    status code: 400, request id: 35f1ec73-18e3-11e8-9f54-8793fe969339
```

Anyone has an idea why?

Comment: What was the solution?

Answer (score 2):

I've been waiting for Go support for too long, so I decided to implement it myself.

https://github.com/chainifynet/aws-encryption-sdk-go

features:

- Message Format Version 1 and 2
- AWS KMS Master Key Provider with a discovery filter
- Raw Master Key provider using static keys
- Comprehensive e2e testing ensuring compatibility with `aws-encryption-sdk-cli`

Answer (score 0):

The Go dev guide has KMS examples of encrypting/decrypting in Go: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/kms-example-encrypt-data.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/kms-example-decrypt-blob.html, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Doug's comment is incorrect.

Anyways, are you setting the encryption context during encryption? If so, this will fail your decryption. Can you post some sample code of your encryption?

Comment: There is something wrong with the `type DecryptInput`. Some of these values are not accessible. What is encryption Context supposed to be in Decrypt output?

Answer (score 0):

From your posted ciphertext I can see that you encrypted your data with an encryption context (as @Xibz mentions).  You need to supply this same encryption context when Decrypt'ing your data.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/concepts.html#encryption-context