# Persistent InvalidCiphertextException using KMS to Decrypt

Tags: amazon-kms, aws-sdk-go

I have generated my KMS key in Golang using this code

```
// Create the key
result, err := svc.CreateKey(&kms.CreateKeyInput{
    Tags: []*kms.Tag{
        {
            TagKey:   aws.String("CreatedBy"),
            TagValue: aws.String("User"),
        },
    },
})
```

And this is the line causing the error during Decrypt

```
        //Get body bytes
        body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        //base64Text := make([]byte, base64.StdEncoding.EncodedLen(len(body)))
        //base64.StdEncoding.Encode(base64Text, []byte(body))
        //Needs decrypting?
        var newfile *bytes.Reader
        if decrypt == true {
            log.Println("Now decrypting data")
            log.Println("resp.SSECustomerAlgorithm : ", resp.SSECustomerAlgorithm)
            log.Println("resp.SSEKMSKeyId : ", aws.StringValue(resp.SSEKMSKeyId)) //right key found.
            newkms := inputfs.NewKms()
            //n := map[string]*string{"CreatedBy": aws.String("User") }
            params := &kms.DecryptInput{
                CiphertextBlob: body,
                //EncryptionContext:n,
            }
            output, err := newkms.Decrypt(params)
            if err != nil {
                log.Println("Decrypt error :", err)
            }
            newbody := output.Plaintext
            newfile = bytes.NewReader(newbody)
        }
```

Error at Decrypt error

```
 Decrypt error : InvalidCiphertextException: 
status code: 400, request id: b69a8634-1784-4c57-8d3d-2439041249fe
```

What could possibly cause this? Nothing I do seems to work. Here is a related question: [Decrypting using AWS go sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48956704/decrypting-using-aws-go-sdk) but i don't see the answer.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my objects were already decrypted.
My objects were originally KMS encrypted using S3 PUTobject operation.
AWS S3 automatically decrypts such objects on S3 GETobject operation.
I can actually get the particular object in plaintext, so this supports the above statement.
See [Request Headers and the Amazon S3 API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingKMSEncryption.html)